# Represent $\frac1{(1+x)^2}$ as a power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

Represent $\frac1{(1+x)^2}$ as a power series.

if we put $\frac1{1+2x+x^2}$:

$$
\sum _{n=1}^{+\infty}\left(-x-x^2\right)^n
$$

and if we differentiate $\frac{-1}{1+x}$:

$$
-\sum _{n=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^nn\cdot x^{n-1}
$$

are the expressions right?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The geometric sum would be:

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(-2x-x^2\right)^n$

Geometric sums start the summation at $n=0$.  Also, your denominator is $1-(-2x-x^2)$, not $1-(-x-x^2)$.

The power series you wrote for the derivative of $-\dfrac{1}{1+x}$ is correct.

Comment: but are they equivalent?

Comment: The sum $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(-2x-x^2\right)^n$ has a radius of convergence of $|-2x-x^2| < 1$.  When solved, this gives $-1<x<-1+\sqrt{2}$.  But, the power series for the derivative has a radius of convergence of $-1<x<1$.

Comment: so which one should i choose?

Comment: @DMCL Well, one is a series of powers of $x$, the other is a series of powers of $-2x^2-x$. Presumably your request for which one to "choose" means this is for a homework exercise, in which case you should ask yourself: how often do homework exercises ask for you to write series of powers of $-2x^2-x$ instead of powers of $x$? Would it ever ask this of you without saying this?

Comment: @DMCL, personally, I would choose the one with the larger radius of convergence.  For all $-1<x<-1+\sqrt{2}$, they should evaluate to the same number.  If you were to manipulate the geometric sum containing $-2x-x^2$ a little (for example with the binomial formula), you would get:

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}(2x)^k x^{2(n-k)}$

With some effort, you can show that the coefficient for $x^n$ is $(-1)^{n+1}n$, which agrees with the other power series.

Comment: ahhh! there is an exercise below also asking to represent 1/(1+x)^3 so it might be the derivated one. PS: i am preparing for an exame. thanks

Answer (score 4):

Represent $$\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$$ as an infinite series.

Use the geometric sequence to get,

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n=\frac {1}{1-x}$$,
replace $x$ by $-x$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-x)^n=\frac {1}{1-(-x)}=\frac {1}{1+x}$$
take the derivative,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n(-1)^n(x)^{n-1}=\frac {-1}{(1+x)^2}$$
Multiplying by $-1$ we get
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n(-x)^{n-1}=\frac {1}{(1+x)^2}$$.

To answer your question, Yes.

Answer (score 2):

Here is particularly simple method:

Just divide 1 by $(1 + x)^2$

To do this we expand $(1 + x)^2 = 1 + 2x + x^2$

Now we divide the one by this quantity

$$\frac{1}{1 + 2x + x^2} = 1 - \frac{2x + x^2}{1 + 2x + x^2} $$

And perform the next phase of division

$$ 1 - \frac{2x + x^2}{1 + 2x + x^2} = 1 - 2x + \frac{ x^2 + x^3}{1 + 2x + x^2}$$

And keep repeating:

$$ 1 - 2x + \frac{ 3x^2 + 2x^3}{1 + 2x + x^2} = 1 - 2x + 3x^2 - \frac{4x^3 + 3x^4}{1 + 2x + x^2} $$

Which will generate all the terms you seek. Now observe that on each round of division the leading term on the expression (the lower power one) being divided ends up in the series and the term right after that (always having coefficient one less than the coefficient before it) will be added (or subtracted) with 2 times the previous coefficient meaning it will have coefficient  $(k-1) + 2(k+1) = k -1 + 2k + 2 = k +1$ meaning every coefficient will have magnitude one greater than the one preceding it.

That allows you to confidently say:

$$ \sum_{i=0}^\infty{(-1)^i(i+1)x^i} = \frac{1}{(1+x)^2} $$